# Why does Dreamweaver save the same .php file twice?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dreamweaver, www

- I am creating a website on localhost (WAMP) as of now.
- I have set up the testing server
- the new php files that I create are saved in a sub-foldor of *www*
  folder specific for my website.  [ C:\wamp64\www\mysite ]
- Though, a duplicate of the file is saved outside the folder, in the *www* folder as well. [ C:\wamp64\www]
- When I edit either file, both are edited.

I am confused as to why does this happen and how does this affect my website development process(Amateur developer).

Comment: How is Apache configured regarding the `DocumentRoot`?   Is `C:\wamp64\www` the general `DocumentRoot` and `C:\wamp64\www\mysite` is the `DocumentRoot` for a specific `VirtualHost` (site)?

Comment: I am unaware of how Apache functions nor am I familiar with DocumentRoot folder. I have downloaded WAMP server in C drive which has been saved as 'wamp64'. Within it exist the 'www' folder and the 'mysite' folder (self-created) in which I save all my dreamweaver files.